# how to update iOS after direct download

Tags: iphone, ios

How do I update iOS after downloading the files from a direct link??

Comment: Uhm, I'd say with iTunes?

Comment: Well... I'll update the iOS with iTunes.. it's just that I downloaded the update file from a direct link http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-1011.20110503.q7fGc/iPhone3,1_4.3.3_8J2_Restore.ipsw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iTunes, select your device, and hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and press "Restore". A dialog box will pop up asking you for the location of the ipsw file. Select your downloaded file and you're good to go!

Comment: I tried that last time but all the settings were gone, had to download the apps again, then had to authorize the system again for downloads etc.. is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Not sure... You can try keeping the filename exactly the same, and moving the file to `%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates`, and then pressing "Update". iTunes _should_ see the downloaded file and not try to download it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding SHIFT and click on "Restore" in the Device Details page.